# Java: bad output with scanner

Tags: java, debugging, console-application, java.util.scanner

I recently posted a question about a scanner not giving the expected results and learned that my problem was that I wasn't flushing the scanner with `.nextLine()`. I am confused with a program I'm working on because I am flushing the scanner properly but when I test my program, if - when prompted for a number - I type a string, I get erroneous output. It repeats the same loop twice.

The top of the loop has a call to nextLine() and the else block that deals with invalid input such as the string I'm typing has a call to nextLine() as well. But still somehow I'm getting bad output

So to be specific, here is a sample of the bad output with user input in **bold** and the problematic output in italics

Enter the left-hand value: **2**

Enter operator: **-**

Enter the right-hand value: **t**

*Invalid Input*

*Enter operator* (+ - * or / :

*Invalid Operator*

*Enter operator* (+ - * or / :

The four lines above are automatically spit out to the console.

Here is the code snip, with a big comment where the bad code is. I would have posted just the while block where the issue is but since the while block is most of the program and the whole program is only a bit larger than that section, I figured it would be better to post all of it.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Calculator{

public static void main(String[] args){

    double leftHandVal = 0.0;

    //Output Title & Instructions
    System.out.print("!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!\n");
    System.out.print("!\t\t\t\t!\n");
    System.out.print( "!\t   INSTRUCTIONS\t\t!\n");
    System.out.print("!\t\t\t\t!\n");
    System.out.print("!   INPUT\t\tOUTPUT\t\t!\n");
    System.out.print("!  *******\t         *********\t\t!\n");
    System.out.print("!   c or C\t\tClear\t\t!\n");
    System.out.print("!   q or Q\t\tQuit\t\t!\n");
    System.out.print("!     +\t\tAddition\t\t!\n");
    System.out.print("!     -\t\tSubtraction\t!\n");
    System.out.print("!     *\t\tMultiplication\t!\n");
    System.out.print("!     /\t\tDivision\t\t!\n");
    System.out.print("!\t\t\t\t!\n");
    System.out.print("!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!\n\n");

    while(true){

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        char op = '\n';//(+, -, *, or /) will use in switch statement for their ascii decimal values

        System.out.print("Enter the left-hand value: ");

        //these blocks allow the code at the very bottom to not erroneously ask the user for extra input with hasNext() calls 
        if(input.hasNext("c") || input.hasNext("C")){//even though its unlikely for a user to clear so early...just in case
            leftHandVal = 0.0;
        }
        else if(input.hasNext("q") || input.hasNext("Q")){//even though its unlikely for a user to quit so early...just in case
            op = 113;//assign q for quit code
        }  
        else if(input.hasNextDouble()){
            leftHandVal = input.nextDouble(); 


            /*
             *
             *BAD CODE INSIDE WHILE BELOW
             *BAD CODE INSIDE WHILE BELOW
             *BAD CODE INSIDE WHILE BELOW
             *BAD CODE INSIDE WHILE BELOW
             *
             */

            while(true){

                input.nextLine();
                double rightHandVal = 0.0;

                System.out.print("\nEnter operator (+ - * or / : ");

                if(input.hasNext()){
                    op = input.next().charAt(0);
                }

                //if user wishes to cancel or quit on operator prompt, break out of inner while to access the clear and quit code
                if(op == 99 || op == 67){
                    op = 99;
                    break;
                }
                else if(op == 113 || op == 81){
                    op = 113;
                    break;
                }
                else if((op != 43) && (op != 45) && (op != 42) && (op != 47)){//if invalid operator, restart inner while
                    System.out.print("Invalid Operator");

                    continue;
                }

                System.out.print("Enter the right-hand value: ");

                if(input.hasNextDouble()){
                    rightHandVal = input.nextDouble();

                    switch(op){
                        case 43:
                            System.out.printf("%.3f + %.3f = %.3f", leftHandVal, rightHandVal, (leftHandVal + rightHandVal));
                            leftHandVal += rightHandVal;
                            break;
                        case 45: 
                            System.out.printf("%.3f - %.3f = %.3f", leftHandVal, rightHandVal, (leftHandVal - rightHandVal));
                            leftHandVal -= rightHandVal;
                            break;
                        case 42:
                            System.out.printf("%.3f * %.3f = %.3f", leftHandVal, rightHandVal, (leftHandVal * rightHandVal));
                            leftHandVal *= rightHandVal;
                            break;
                        case 47:
                            System.out.printf("%.3f / %.3f = %.3f", leftHandVal, rightHandVal, (leftHandVal / rightHandVal));
                            leftHandVal /= rightHandVal;
                            break;

                    }
                }

                //if clear or quit requested from prompt for right-hand value, break to reach the clear and quit code
                else if(input.hasNext("c") || input.hasNext("C")){
                    op = 99;
                    break;
                }
                else if(input.hasNext("q") || input.hasNext("Q")){
                    op = 113;
                    break;
                }
                else{
                    System.out.print("Invalid Input");

                }

            } 
        }

        //if c || C reset op to null and restart outer while
        if(op == 99 || op == 67){
            op = '\n';
            leftHandVal = 0.0;
            continue;
        }
        //else if q || Q, prompt user with a popup to confirm.
        if(op == 113 || op == 81){
            int response = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "QUIT CALCULATOR?", null, JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
            if(response == 0){
                System.exit(0);
            }
            continue;
        }



    }
}
}
```

Comment: What is the question here?

Comment: What @BigAl said and also maybe you should first try evaluating characters as characters since they are characters. Doing that may very well not fix the problem you are having but the way you are doing it right now (evaluating as integers) is nuts either way.

Comment: The question is why - when I input a letter in the prompt to enter a right hand value - do I get multiple outputs even though I am using input.nextLine() to flush the scanner.

Comment: @Justin I highly recommend you change all of your code so it evaluates chars as chars instead of chars as ints. Personally my best guess is your problem lies with this line: `else if((op != 43) &&...other vague conditions` because that is the entrance point for a continue but it's hard to say until we don't have to pull up an ASCII chart to understand a single line of your code.

Comment: Just open the docs for [`Scanner` class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine()) and read what the methods actually do. You seem not to have a clue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
else if(input.hasNext("c") || input.hasNext("C"))
{
  op = 99;
  break;
}
else if(input.hasNext("q") || input.hasNext("Q")){
  op = 113;
  break;
}
else{
  System.out.print("Invalid Input");

}
```

in this code, when you enter "t" for right hand value, you just check for `hasNext();` finally it comes to **else** and prints Invalid Input.

But **input** still has value "t", so it goes to second **while** loop starting again and

```
                System.out.print("\nEnter operator (+ - * or / : ");

                if(input.hasNext()){
                    op = input.next().charAt(0);
                }
```

checks for **input.hasNext()** which already has "t", so takes "t" and continues.

Solution is to flush the "t" before coming to the while loop.